# How to write Unit testing for email and password validation?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I do have the following small function for http POST request where I check the email and password regarding validation...

What would be the best approach to implement a unit testing for it?

```
MAIL_RegExp = /^\w+([d\\+1\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/i;
Pass_RegExp = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,30}$/i;
storeUser(uemail:string, upass:string) {
    if (!this.MAIL_RegExp.test(uemail)) {
        return false;
    } else if (!this.Pass_RegExp.test(upass)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this.uService.regUser(uemail, upass)
        .subscribe(
            (res) => {this.openDialog(uemail);},
            (err) => {this.errMsg = err;}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the first two tests are just testing the validation. You probably need many different versions of the all of the tests to test that your regular expressions are working properly.

```
it(`should return false when storeUser is called with an invalid email`, async(() => {
  const invalidEmail = 'sample invalid Email goes here';
  const validPassword = 'sample valid Password goes here';

  let result = storeUser(invalidEmail, validPassword);

  expect(result).toEqual(false);
}));

it(`should return false when storeUser is called with an invalid password`, async(() => {
  const validEmail = 'sample valid Email goes here';
  const invalidPassword = 'sample invalid Password goes here';

  let result = storeUser(validEmail, invalidPassword);

  expect(result).toEqual(false);
}));
```

So the third one is a bit more interesting. First you have to get hold of the injected uService. Then you need to spy on the regUser function so you can test whether it has been called. But you also need to return an Observable because if you don't the call to subscribe will throw an error. Because you are not using anything from the Observable in the test below an Observable of anything should work.

```
it(`should call regUser on uService when storeUser is called with valid Email and Password`, async(() => {
  let uService = TestBed.get(Type of uService);
  spyOn(uService, 'regUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of(An instance of the return type of regUser));
  const validEmail = 'sample valid Email goes here';
  const validPassword = 'sample valid Password goes here';

  let result = storeUser(validEmail, validPassword);

  expect(uService.regUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

The final thing you could test is that errors are getting stored in the this.errMsg and openDialog function is getting called. To do this you would need to setup your returned Observable correctly and spy on the openDialog function. Thinking about it, it is possible that openDialog may break the above test so you may need to spy on it to stub it.

Comment: Great... helpful explanation. I'll make the necessary changes and give it a try.

Comment: @lain:Runs fine except `spyOn(uService, regUser).and.returnValue(new Observable.of(An instance of the return type of regUser));`throws error: `[ts] Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.` What I couldn't understand is `An instance of the return type of regUser`. This should get the instance of the service where `regUser` is defined. So, something like: `new Observable.of(An instance of the return type of regUser)`. When I remove `new`, works fine, but test throws: `Failed: <spyOn> : function (email, pass) {....}() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)`

Comment: Sorry that was a sloppy line of code. Yes the new keyword is a mistake it shouldn't have been there. Also in the spyOn function the first argument is the object that has the method, the second is a string that is the name of the method that is being spied on. (I've put quotes round regUser that were missing).

Comment: @lain: Great. Function has been update, but one small issue: `Expected spy regUser to have been called.` this is the update:it(`should call regUser on uService when storeUser is called with valid Email and Password`, async(() => {let uService=TestBed.get(uService);spyOn(uService,'regUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of(uService));const validEmail=['test@test.com','test@test.co.uk'];const validPassword='!q2wAscb';let result=component.storeUser(validEmail, validPassword);expect(uService.regUser).toHaveBeenCalled();})); An idea? Have been searching, but couldn't fix it.

Comment: My first suspicion would be that one of your regular expressions is failing. Unfortunately I can't test it as I can't get regular expressions to work on my machine as it won't recognise the function test.

Comment: I've managed to get my test working and it looks like it's your email that's failing. If I put in const validEmail = 'test@test.co.uk'; then it works.

Comment: True. Working for me as well except the line regarding. `this.openDialog(uemail)`. The test fails then. Error: `Failed: No component factory found for OpenDialogueComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`. But I already have `entryComponents` in the `app.module.ts`. So, therefore I can't figure out what still should be fixed/changed.

Comment: My openDialog(uemail) is just a dummy function as you haven't listed your code for it. However your error sounds like it is calling another component that you have included in your NgModule. Remember in your tests you have to include components that you are using in you TestBed declaration. However assuming openDialog(uemail) is not a private function it might be better to spyOn openDialog(uemail) and just test that it is called and use other tests to test openDialog(uemail).